# Hacking exercise / How can I pass a new terminal command to an existing terminal command?

Tags: terminal, code-injection, payload

If we got this command line:

```
python file.py --gsgds dsgsdg --dg dgdg --dg 'gdgd'
```

And now, let's say we want to break this command and run another command while it is running, something like that:

```
python file.py --gsgds dsgsdg --dg dgdg --dg '`sleep 10`'
```

When I try to add a **`sleep 10`** between the two quotes, it doesn't work. Please keep in mind that I must break the command between the two quotes. ('[inject here]')

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "breaking" the command. You are essentially passing a command line argument to the program? Do you want to just pass the output of another command to `python` or do you want to run another program simultaneously? Can you please rectify the question to indicate what you want? Preferably add a sample output or more details.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. English isn't my native language, so please try to understand me: Let's say some website runs this command line in their terminal: python file.py --arg1 blabla --arg2 blabla --arg3 'blablabla'. We have the ability to change one of the arguments (In this case, arg3). I want to run the command sleep 10 before their command runs, so it should be something like that: python file.py --arg1 blabla --arg2 blabla --arg3 '`Sleep 10`'. The problem here is that they use single quotes, so I can't really inject new command into their existed command. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Okie, so you want your output to be `python file.py --arg1 blabla --arg2 blabla --arg3 'sleep 10'` or do you mean to do something like run `sleep 10` in addition to running the python command?

Comment: I want to run the command 'sleep 10' out of their existed command eventually. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: I can't just run the command by itself, I have permission to change the argument arg3 only. How can I use arg3 to run 'sleep 10'?

Comment: And by the way, I see that you keep on saying python. I just want to clarify that it has nothing to do with python specifically. It can be any other command.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take for example, we have `bash` shell running in the terminal. There are several characters which have special meaning in the bash shell. You can read more in the [bash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html) manual.

Let's take for example, `;` in `bash`.
You can easily run `sleep 10` after your python command using `;`. Here's one way:

```
python file.py --gsgds dsgsdg --dg dgdg --dg ''; sleep 1; echo 'Done'
```

where you pass `'; sleep 1; echo 'Done` in the third arg.

Some shells add restriction on what characters can/ cannot be used so it's up to you to try out what works.

Comment: Is there another way of doing that? It looks like the server knows how to handle that.

Comment: That happens in the server when I try your suggestion: --arg3 'bla'\''; sleep 1; echo '\''Done' --arg3 blabla

Comment: Can you update the question with the error or share it here? I do see there are extra `\\` in there

Comment: I do not think you understand me correctly. I'm having a test and there is this website that runs a random python terminal command. One argument of their existed command is changeable. I basically need to inject another command through this argument and make it sleep for 60 seconds. Some may call it "Command Injection". Can someone help me, please?

Comment: And another important thing to mention here is that this specific website has some defends, when I tried your suggestion with the `'; sleep 1; echo 'Done`, the server returned `--arg3 'bla'\''; sleep 1; echo '\''Done' --arg3 blabla`.